# Excel VBA code that displays a 14 day weather forecast

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to see if anyone can help me in making this Excel VBA code a little faster in rendering the data from the weather site I am using.  Maybe instead of getting all 14 days it includes in the site, could I get help in getting just 10 days? Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
Sub MiamiWeather()

   Dim HTTP As Object, HTML As Object, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    
    Set HTML = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
    Set HTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    myURL = "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/3881cd527264bc7c99b6b541473c0085e75aa026b6bd99658c56ad9bb55bd96e"
    
    HTTP.Open "GET", myURL, False
    HTTP.send
    
    HTML.body.innerHTML = HTTP.responseText
    
    Set objCollection = HTML.getElementsByTagName("p")
    i = 0
    
    Do While i < objCollection.Length And j < 20
        If objCollection(i).getAttribute("data-testid") = "wxPhrase" Then
            j = j + 1
            Range("A" & j) = objCollection(i).PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
            Range("B" & j) = objCollection(i).PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
      
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set HTML = Nothing
    Set HTTP = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: If you want to load fewer days just add a condition on the loop:

Do While i < objCollection.Length And j < 10

Comment: Using some simple timing code (e.g. `Debug.Print "Section:"; (Timer - stTime)*1000;"ms"`) I ran and profiled your code. About 50% of the running time is spent in that While loop, 30% is spent loading the HTML document from the HTTP response, the other 20% spent in the Get request. Consequently I'd say the best optimisations come from the while loop, and you may want to profile that in more detail. It's true, stopping after j = 10 rather than 14 saves ~ 25% of the loop time, however looping over all `<p>` elements is wasteful and you may want to try `getElementsByClassName` to narrow the search

Comment: Thanks for timing the code, Greedo.  I was working with a code that had getElementsByClassName, but it stopped giving me the first date in the forecast of today's forecast of the summary.

Comment: Could I easily change the code to getElementsByClassName?

Answer (score 3):

The real question here is how to get only the `p` tags with a `data-testid` with the value of `wxPhrase`. This can be done using `querySelectorAll()`.

> Document.querySelectorAll("p[data-testid='wxPhrase']")

See [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

You will need to add a reference to the Microsoft HTML Object Library and declare you document variable as `HTMLDocument`.

> Dim Document As HTMLDocument

[image: Reference Window]

Loading the values into an Array will offer you the best performance.  It will not make a noticeable difference if you return 10 days or all the days of the month.

### Refactored Code

```
Sub MiamiWeather()
    Dim Data As Variant
    Data = MiamiWeatherData
    
    Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Date", "Tempature")
    Range("A2").Resize(UBound(Data), 2).Value = Data
    
End Sub

Function MiamiWeatherData()
    Const URL = "https://weather.com/weather/tenday/l/3881cd527264bc7c99b6b541473c0085e75aa026b6bd99658c56ad9bb55bd96e"
    Dim responseText As String
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        responseText = .responseText
    End With
    
    Dim Document As HTMLDocument
    Set Document = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")
    Document.body.innerHTML = responseText

    Dim Children As IHTMLDOMChildrenCollection
    Set Children = Document.querySelectorAll("p[data-testid='wxPhrase']")
    Dim Results As Variant
    ReDim Results(1 To Children.Length, 1 To 2)
    Dim r As Long
    
    For r = 0 To Children.Length - 1
        Results(r + 1, 1) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
        Results(r + 1, 2) = Children(r).PreviousSibling.FirstChild.innerText
    Next
    
    MiamiWeatherData = Results
End Function
```

Comment: I think you forgot to swop out your late-bound htmlfile for early bound New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

Comment: @QHarr I didn't bother adding a reference to the to `Microsoft XML, v?.0`.  I'm referencing `Microsoft HTML Object Library` so that I will have intellisense for the HTML elements.

Comment: I mean I think this _Set Document = CreateObject("HTMLFILE")_ should be _Set Document = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument_ to stick with early binding. `